# CSS/HTML code isn't working, font isn't getting applied

Tags: html, css, input

When I try to run this CSS/HTML code (this is in webkit browsers), it doesn't work. The font in the input box is does not have the Lato font applied:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300' rel='stylesheet'
        type='text/css'>
        <title>Dumb Search</title>
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"
        />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../ds.png" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, user-scalable = no, initial-scale = 0.8">
        <style>
            .box {
                padding:20px;
                width:290px;
                box-shadow:0px 1px 3px -1px #c3c3c3;
                background-color:white;
                color:gray;
                font-family:Lato;
                text-align:left;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#f5f5f5">
        <center>
            <br>
            <div style="position:relative;width:342px;">
                <form action="searchcompleted.php" style="display:inline;">
                    <input name="q" value="Search, or tap the camera" class="box" style="border:0;outline:0;width:340px;color:#A0A0A0;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;"
                    onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search, or tap the camera') {this.value = '';}"
                    onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search, or tap the camera';}">
                </form>
                <img src="http://i45.tinypic.com/30vkbhj.jpg" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:278px;opacity:0.4;height:30px;padding:15px;padding-right:17px;"
                onclick='void(0);document.getElementById("thisone").click();'>
                <form style="display:inline;" action="http://www.dumbsearch.com/dumbocr/post.php"
                method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="sniff">
                    <input accept="image/*" type="file" style="display:none;" id="thisone"
                    onchange='document.getElementById("scan").style.display="block";' name="photo">
                    <div onclick='void(0);document.getElementById("sniff").submit();' style="position:absolute;top:65px;left:195px;background-color:white;border:0;box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px -1px #C3C3C3;padding:20px;color:#0EBFE9;padidng-left:25px;padding-right:25px;z-index:4;display:none;font-family:Lato;"
                    id="scan">Touch to scan</div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="box">ï»¿</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Thanks you so muchhh! in advance!

**Edit:** Look here: http://pastehtml.com/view/cokmdi9yg.html

Comment: The font doesn't get applied in this part of the code? `<input name="q" value="Search, or tap the camera" class="box" style="border:0;outline:0;width:340px;color:#A0A0A0;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;font-family:Lato;" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search, or tap the camera') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search, or tap the camera';}">`

Comment: What browser are you using?  @font-face rules don't work in IE 8 and earlier.

Comment: @JLRishe Yeah, I said webkit, (like safari and chrome)

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/HZZKG/

Comment: @kennypu yeah but check ths out: http://pastehtml.com/view/cokmdi9yg.html

Comment: the font is applied there as well on chrome.

Comment: @kennypu but not the font size. the font size should be like this: http://pastehtml.com/view/cokntazl4.html

Comment: Why should the font size be like that? You aren't applying font size to the class in the first one.

Comment: you should specify font size in your description. font, and font size are two different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is apparently not about font at all, or about a Google font in particular, but about *font size*. Browsers usually apply a reduced font size in input boxes, something like 90% of copy text size. If you inspect the page using developer tools (F12) in Chrome, you can see that one of the declarations applied to the element is `font: -webkit-small-control`. This sets both font family and font size, and you are overriding just the font family part now.

For example, to make the text in the input box the same as in the document body in general (or, formally, the same as in the surrounding element), just add the following CSS rule:

```
input { font-size: 100%; }
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. Sorry for the confusion everybody. My question was unclear!

Answer (score 3):

try this in font family

```
 @font-family
{
font-family: FirstFont;
src: url('.ttf');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Type the `font family` declaration like so: `font-family: 'Lato';` It must be in quotes.

Answer (score -1):

font family 'lato' not available in CSS so pls import the 'Lato'using this code. download the ttf and eot file of Lato.

```
@font-face
{
font-family: FirstFont;
src: url('.ttf'),
     url('.eot'); 
}
```

Comment: no Ive used lato before look here: http://pastehtml.com/view/cokmdi9yg.html (via google fonts)